# Android Javamail custom Authentication

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail

So, I realize that SASL is not implemented in android, and that consequently the javamail oauth2 methods won't out of the box.

However, according to the google api docs for gmail imap (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol) it would seem fairly trivial to get an auth token, encode it, and send the 'AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 ' to the server manually.

My problem: I want to use the javamail IMAP functions (don't want to handle IMAP protocol commands and response munging myself), but I need a way to simply insert the proper authentication command - not the traditional login username password.

Can this be done and what would be the easiest way to go about it? Could I create my own authentication method and implement this easily?

Alternatively, can I create the connection and then hand this off to an IMAPStore (doubt this would work as it creates and manages a connection pool).

---Edit---

Just to be more specific, the javax.security.sasl method is not implemented in Android which  Imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator relies on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a working jar with sasl support for imap (for smtp you have to issue the command as you said because java mail for android doesn't have the sasl infrastructure for smtp). 
All I did was to add the packages javax.security.sasl and javax.security.auth.callback to the java mail for android source and repackage it. I had to put the in a different namaspace, myjavax.security.sasl etc. because otherwise android build system complains that the package contains core libraries, not sure why it doesn't complain for javax.mail which is in a core namespace anyway (javax). I also had to change some import for the new namespace in some classes, but basically are the packeges classes themselves and com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator. 
With this I could successfully authenticate to gmail imap server using the oauth 2 token I got from the Android AccountManager, I didn't try anything else. For smtp, you can look at my answer here [Javamail api in android using XOauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503303/javamail-api-in-android-using-xoauth/12821612#12821612)
I think it's possible to make smtp work with Sasl getting the new classes from here http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/show/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/smtp which have Sasl support for smtp.
I think this is perfectly fine because all I do is adding some GPL classes, the one that I added are from the JDK.
Hope this helps, if you need the jars or some more explanation on how to do it, just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and discussion above - I ended up just asking for username/password in my app, though I would still prefer oauth 2 and sasl (I am not doing anything with SMTP). do you have a link to the jars or source that you used?

Comment: Here's a zip with the source and the jar. It's only the mail part of javamail, you need the activation and additional jar from javamail for android. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3092259/javamail.zip You can export a new jar with jardesc if you need.

Comment: @alex the code you attached is java project.Is thery any sample  you created for android,please share it.Thanks in advance

Comment: for smtp  sender - SMTPTransport works just fine, checking mails w IMAP does not work w OAuth2

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this without hacking the JavaMail classes.

Can't you just use username/password authentication?

Comment: Ok, that is what I was afraid of. I could use username/password, but would rather use tokens if possible so users don't have to enter their credentials into my app, just "approve" it the first time I ask for a token...

Comment: Mhhh I noticed checking the source that the solution in my answer below might be a problem with Oracle licensing per the classpath exception in the licence. Basically as I understand it, the namespace should remain javax.* . If so, is it possible to make android stop complaining about core classes? After all, it doesn't complain with javax.mail in the java mail for android "port". I think Bill Shannon should be able to answer this :p, just noticed your name here and on the source I was looking at :D

Comment: I have no idea which classes Android complains about and why.  Too bad it's not really Java, huh?  ;-)  I don't remember the classpath exception saying anything about javax.*, but IANAL.

Comment: Android doesn't have everything in javax.security.sasl and some classes in javax.security.auth.callback. All those classes have no other dependencies, so it's safe to add them, they are even all implementend in harmony so I don't understand why they didn't include them in the first place. For java mail in general there are some other dependencies but they are already in the java mail for android package. I was confused about the license, it's not the classpath exception, but the point 3 in LICENSE.txt, java restrictions, but maybe my interpretation is wrong. If so, my solution below it's ok.

Comment: interesting answer from javamail dev. so, there is no way to make it work with OAuth2.0, is there? And it is not an option these days to use user/password cause gmail will bug you to death with them insecurity warnings.

Answer (score 0):

From https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2:

> Starting with JavaMail 1.5.5, support for OAuth2 authentication is built-in and no longer requires SASL