# How to use gmail OAUTH2 with older javamail versions in Android application

Tags: android, email, oauth, jakarta-mail

I did my research and could not find an answer, so, I am asking for your help.

Is it possible to connect to gmail imap server using 1.4.1 javamail version (please, don't ask why) using OAUTH2 protocol? OAUTH is supported in javamail since 1.5.2, but there are many problems when I use 1.5.2 in Android app that I can not solve.

I am stuck with 1.4.1, but I hope that there is a "hack" that can allow me to connect to gmail without having to "allow less secure applications". Like, sending "access token" as password or something.

Any help is appreciated.

If not, is there any way (or library) I can use to connect to gmail server with OAUTH and then use that socket in javamail to retreive e-mail messages.
For example, I connect to server by sending raw data and then pass that "connection" to javamail store so it can use it to do all other things.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but I get the impression that lots of other people are using newer versions of JavaMail with Android, so you might be better off trying to figure out why that's not working for you.  In any event, you might be able to use the Google-supplied OAUTH2 support with JavaMail 1.4.1, but again I haven't tried that.  1.4.1 is really very old.

Comment: I found solution in the accepted answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682093/access-gmail-using-imap-with-accountmanager-token