# send mail to recepient using an android app with kivy

Tags: android, python, mobile, kivy

I am creating an app in android using kivy python. I am not understanding how can I upload a file from android mobile to any email in background without intimating the user.
If I mail the file to any email id, it will reflect to sent items in the users mail. Many android apps do such things but I am not able to understand How can I do that?

I dont find any example as well about mailing files or uploading files from android app using python kivy. Can anyone guide me in this?

please do not downvote. If anyone have any information share it so that I can understand and learn the things.

Answer (score 1):

Existing android email clients do not have a feature which directly allows you to send an email without user interaction due to fear of spammy apps and other security issues. The only way I can think of to get an email client to "reflect ... sent items in the users mail" is to create your own email client which doesn't require user interaction.

It's either that or assume your user has a gmail address, in which case you could port OAuth 2 into kivy python:

[Send e-mail in Android without user interacton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106774/send-e-mail-in-android-without-user-interacton/15107778#15107778)

Your question is basically a duplicate of the above question, with the change being that the solution be in kivy, neither of which have a built-in way to send email without user interaction.