# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity (trying to send a mail)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use the code found [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

to send an email from an Android app.

I'm using ADT Build 22.0.5

I've seen many people having this issue but for different reasons and I really can't get my head around it.

This is the complete error log

```
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not         execute method of the activity
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at    android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     ... 11 more
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.naghe.Mail
09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at com.example.naghe.NagheMainActivity.sendMessage(NagheMainActivity.java:21)
```

and this is my main activity

```
package com.example.naghe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NagheMainActivity extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_naghe_main);

        }
    public void sendMessage (View view) {
        Mail m = new Mail("test", "test");
        String[] toArr = {"mail}; 
        m.setTo(toArr); 
        m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com"); 
        m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
        m.setBody("Email body."); 

        try { 
          m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

          if(m.send()) { 
            Toast.makeText(NagheMainActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          } else { 
            Toast.makeText(NagheMainActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          } 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
          //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
        } 
    }
}
```

This is the XML, it's only a button, since i'm testing this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".NagheMainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and YES, I do have the class Mail in my project.
You can find that class on the very first link on this post, but here it is

Mail.java

```
package com.example.naghe;

import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

  public void setTo(String[] _to) { 
        this._to = _to; 
      } 

  public void setFrom(String _from){
      this._from = _from;
  }

  public void setSubject(String _subject){
      this._subject = _subject;
  }
  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

any help would be very much apreciated!

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.naghe.Mail. DO you have the class Mail in your app?

Comment: to use the code in the link you gave it says Before we begin, you'll need to download a few files via the link below - this is a special version of the JavaMail API, which was written specifically for Android. Looks like you have not added jars properly to your projects libs folder

http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list

Comment: Thank you Raghunandan I have downloaded that already and the Javax.mail-1.5.0.jar, activation.jar, additional.jar and mail.jar are already in my build bath

Comment: java mail 1.5 won't work on android, it gives a NoClassDefFoundError because it depends on some classes not implemented in android (mainly swing classes but also some classes in javax.security.auth.callback and javax.security.sasl). You need to use only the jars in the java mail for android project. If you set debug to true for smtp you should see which classes it can't find

Comment: Thanks @alex I removed java mail 1.5 from build path, cleaned the project but I keep getting the same error. I'll try debugging it tonight and look for the missing/erroring classes

Comment: Try to look at the code I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503303/javamail-api-in-android-using-xoauth/12821612#12821612 it uses xoauth but it works also with username and password if you set them and modify the authentication related commands.

Answer (score 5):

Its caused by

`09-14 15:53:49.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

means you're referring to a resource which actually not exists (or exist some where else), in your XML

Kindly Cross check the xml widgets you're referring from java or you can post XML file as well (I'll take a look).

also

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.naghe.Mail`

Also check do you have `Mail` class included in your package.