# Acknowledgement Email

Tags: android, email, email-client

I am developing an native android application,to send the email to the registered
      mail id.i do not want any client to send the  mail, it will directly sent the mail
      once user clicked the send mail button in my layout design
    Thanks

Comment: you have to do it from server side. due to security reasons it will ask at least for send button. rest of the things you can do pragmatically i.e. recipient and body.

Comment: @Rahul:Thank you , are you having nay sample link or code for this

Comment: Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});    
 email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
 email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
 email.setType("message/rfc822");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.URLName;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;
import com.sun.mail.util.BASE64EncoderStream;

public class GMailSender {
    private Session session;
    private String token;


    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public GMailSender(Activity ctx) {
        super();
        initToken(ctx);
    }

    public void initToken(Activity ctx) {

        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(ctx);

        Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            Log.d("getToken", "account="+account);  
        }

        Account me = accounts[0]; //You need to get a google account on the device, it changes if you have more than one


        am.getAuthToken(me, "oauth2:https://mail.google.com/", null, ctx, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>(){
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result){
                try{
                    Bundle bundle = result.getResult();
                    token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                    Log.d("initToken callback", "token="+token);    

                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, null);

        Log.d("getToken", "token="+token);
    }



    public SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host, int port, String userEmail,
            String oauthToken, boolean debug) throws Exception {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");

        session = Session.getInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
        SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
        // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
        final String emptyPassword = null;

        /* enable if you use this code on an Activity (just for test) or use the AsyncTask
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
         */

        transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);

        byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1",
                userEmail, oauthToken).getBytes();
        response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

        transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);

        return transport;
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String user,
            String oauthToken, String recipients) {
        try {

            SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com", 587,
                    user, oauthToken, true);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                    body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(recipients));
            smtpTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("test", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

for above download mail.jar and activation.jar for android https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/
or try these links:
 http://nilvec.com/sending-email-without-user-interaction-in-android/
[Javamail api in android using XOauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503303/javamail-api-in-android-using-xoauth)
 http://google-mail-xoauth-tools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/com/google/code/samples/xoauth/XoauthAuthenticator.java

Comment: yea i tried this, it will send the mail client right?, but without client, can i send  directly?