# Authenticating emails with JavaMail on android

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I'm making an android app where I need to send and email from inside the app(without using intent), so I searched on the web and finally decided to use the JavaMail API.
I've built the code to use Gmail email providing email and password from the users but unfortunately Google blocks my emails, doing a search I found this [link](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/updates-on-authentication-for-gmail.html), so apparently Google has changed their authentication protocol to oauth2, and JavaMail don't support it(i think that it don't supports it).
I searched all over the web but can't figure out how to solve it.
Is there any way of making it work again?
Here is my code:

**GMailSender.java:**

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

**Mail.java(Part of it):**

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override public Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
                    try {
                        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(strUserEmail, strUserPassword);
                        sender.sendMail(strSubject, messageFinal, strUserEmail, emailAddress);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                    return null;

                }

            }.execute();
```

**JSSEProvider.java:**

```
package com.provider;


/**
 * @author Alexander Y. Kleymenov
 * @version $Revision$
 */


import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version JavaMail API do you use? Looks like they do support oauth2 and thus gmail.

[From JavaMail Api Page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2)

```
Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"); // required for Gmail
 props.put("mail.imap.sasl.enable", "true");
 props.put("mail.imap.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
 props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
 props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
 Store store = session.getStore("imap");
 store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, oauth2_access_token);
```

UPDATE:

Check this answer on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503303/javamail-api-in-android-using-xoauth)

Comment: I'm using JavaMail-android from this [page](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/)

Comment: I've checked but i the first part of code(with the account manager) gives me lot of errors.                                     Sorry i'm new to programming.

Comment: Can you explain me how to set up the first part of code?